# Making directories in windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, directory

I have about 2000 jpg files in a folder, and I need to make a folder for each of them with the same name. The jpg doesn't necessarily have to be in the same folder. I'm new to batch script, but it seemed like a pretty simple operation. This is what I have so far:

```
for %%i in (*) do md %%i
```

When I run it, it says a subdirectory or file already exists. How do I get it to make a directory even though a file with the same name already exists?

Also, it appears to only loop for the last hundred files. How do I get it to run for all ~2000?

Comment: You cannot have a file and a directory with the same name in the same place, this is simply not possible in Windows! Supposing there is a file `image01.jpg`, should the related directory be called `image01` (no `.jpg` suffix)?

Comment: `do MD %%~dpi` See end of help for `for /?`.

Comment: @aschipfl, you are right! I don't want the .jpg suffix on the directory name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```
@echo off
set "ext=*.jpg"
for %%i in ("%ext%") do ( 
    if not exist "%%~ni" MD "%%~ni" 
)
pause
```

***Edit on 20/07/2016 @20:25***

Calling

```
for /?
```

in the command-line gives help about this syntax (which can be used outside FOR, too, this is just the place where help can be found).

> In addition, substitution of FOR
>   variable references has been enhanced.
>   You can now use the following optional
>   syntax:
>
> ```
> %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
> %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
> %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
> %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
> %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
> %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
> %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
> %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
> %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
> %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
> %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
>                environment variable and expands %I to the
>                fully qualified name of the first one found.
>                If the environment variable name is not
>                defined or the file is not found by the
>                search, then this modifier expands to the
>                empty string
> ```
>
> The modifiers can be combined to get
>   compound results:
>
> ```
> %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
> %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
> %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
> %~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
>                environment variable for %I and expands to the
>                drive letter and path of the first one found.
> %~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line
> ```
>
> In the above examples %I and PATH can
>   be replaced by other valid values. 
>   The %~ syntax is terminated by a valid
>   FOR variable name. Picking upper case
>   variable names like %I makes it more
>   readable and avoids confusion with the
>   modifiers, which are not case
>   sensitive.

There are different letters you can use like `f` for "full path name", `d` for drive letter, `p` for path, and they can be combined. `%~` is the beginning for each of those sequences and a number `I` denotes it works on the parameter `%I` (where `%0` is the complete name of the batch file, just like you assumed).

Comment: This worked exactly how I needed it to! Thank you. Can you explain to me what `%%~ni` does?

Comment: @Idpelegr Check my edit to understand what is `%%~ni` and don't forget to accept this answer and upvote if you found it helpful ! Good luck  !